# How to display Vimeo videos in a Windows 8 app?

Tags: iframe, webview, windows-8, embed, vimeo

I would like to display videos from Vimeo in a Windows 8 app. I have developed an app in C# / XAML and wanted to embed a video in an iframe (via a WebView control).

**This is my code:**

```
string EmbedCode = "<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/33713088?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>";
MyWebView.NavigateToString(EmbedCode);
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Does anyone know how this is done in the official Vimeo app?

Comment: Is the WebView a requirement?

Comment: No. As long as it can be represented in XAML.